# How can I make file/directory/ramdisk be visible as USB-drive in Linux?

Tags: linux, files, mount, usb, freebsd

I have some common issue about mounting something not a USB-drive as USB-drive in Linux.
In that way I want ramdisk/directory/file to be seen as USB-drive in system so I could "insert" it in different software (virtual machines, etc.)
I've heard that there is a way to somehow accomplish it under FreeBSD using [`ctl`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ctl&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+12.2-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html)-utility. But is there a way to do it under Linux?

Unfortunately, there is very little related info on the Internet.